# Twitter gem: bad URI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-gem

I updated my Twitter gem today and the `Twitter.user_timeline("some_user")` no longer works.

I get:

`URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=dalailama`

But when I plug that into my browser, it works fine.

Any ideas why this is? It does this in both production and development.

## Solved

Looks like they just pushed a new release. Updated my gemfile again and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they just pushed a new release. Updated my gemfile again and it works.

## Edit

Apparently is was caused by this bug: https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/253

Comment: Excuse me, which version gave you this mistake? And to what version did you update?

Comment: I think this was the problem https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/253. "This was actually caused by an incompatibility between the latest version of faraday (0.8) and simple_oauth. I've pushed a fix to simple_oauth in version 0.1.6 and require that version in twitter 2.2.3.". Can you please update your answer?